# Name that hinge?

Tags: hinges

We recently acquired an antique dresser with a couple of broken hinges.  We're hoping to be able to replace them, but can't figure out what they're called.  We haven't been able to turn it up on google, and the guys at the local hardware store didn't know either.

The hinges allow a mirror to tilt forward and back between mounts on the two sides.  There's not room for anything that sticks out very far, as in the examples [here](http://robinsonsantiques.com/mirror-swivel-screws/mirror-swivel-screws.htm).  A couple pictures of the busted hinges are below, plus our illustration of where they go on the dresser.

[image: Hinge pictures]

Comment: On the assumption that the other part of the hinge is still on the other wooden part, and replacements don't match well, I'd be welding them back together.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a **mirror swivel** movement or hinge but you have an inset one and not an outset one like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try sending a picture to these people and see if they can match it.
http://www.blainewindow.com/index.php

Answer (score -1):

This is a mirror pivot/Tilt Hinge.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This answer gives us nothing beyond what's already answered, and not even much there. We prefer answers that contribute substantially to the topic.